# Источники изучения языка Lua

Tags: разработка-игр, lua

Добрый день,, подскажите источники по изучению языка Lua.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/

Comment: http://ilovelua.narod.ru/

Comment: [Не первый подобный вопрос о Lua](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%5D+lua), так что [поднял вопрос](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40632915#40632915) о создании канонического вопроса с меткой [tag:книги] (ознакомьтесь с [описанием метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/info)). Обычно у нас такие вопросы оффтопик.

Answer (score 1):

Установите Notepad++ и дерзайте :

Learn Lua in 15 Minutes:

http://tylerneylon.com/a/learn-lua/

Lua за 60 минут

https://zserge.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/lua-%D0%B7%D0%B0-60-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82/

Видео уроки :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AXR-D4W9k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o761xoVCsWQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5X82x2ZyXBc

Для новичков не знающих английского видеокурс будет особенно полезен.